# URL output in template is empty

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

URL pattern declaration from views.py

```
url(r'^intentions/(\d+)/$', 'intentions.views.show'),
```

When I am writing address directly, like intentions/1 works ok, but when I trying to display URL show for object like:

```
{% for i in intentions %}
   {% url 'intentions.views.show' i.id as iUrl %}
    <li><a href="{{ iUrl }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

I am ending with empty href. Could someone give me any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Django 1.3 or 1.4, make sure you are [loading the new url tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/#url). Add the following line to the top of your template:

```
{% load url from future %}
```

If you are using Django 1.4 or earlier, and you haven't loaded the new url tag as above, then you need to remove the single quotes from the url pattern:

```
{% url intentions.views.show i.id as iUrl %}
```

As an aside, it's recommended to [name your url pattern](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns):

```
url(r'^intentions/(\d+)/$', 'intentions.views.show', name='show_intention'),
```

Then change your template to:

```
{% for i in intentions %}
  {% url 'show_intention' i.id as iUrl %}
  <li><a href="{{ iUrl }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

you could try

```
{% for i in intentions %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'intentions.views.show' i.id %}"><{{ i }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

don't use {% url 'intentions.views.show' i.id as iUrl %}, it's maybe confused.
Also,you could try modifiy the url as follow

```
 url(r'^intentions/(\d+)/$', 'intentions.views.show', name="intention_view"),
```

then,

```
{% for i in intentions %}
     {% url "intention_view" i.id as iUrl %}
     <li><a href="{{ iUrl }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

If there are also ending empty href,try the first method.

Answer (score 0):

'intentions.views.show'
Also give a name='' to your URL and use it in your template code.